# How to hide NavigationView's top shadow after moving it under Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I created Navigation Drawer activity from Android Studios templates and added this line

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    .../>
```

to not hide "back" button when navdrawer is active. But got some shadow at top that should be transparent. How to remove this shadow?

[image]

Comment: Using a margin for that is kinda hacky. Change the layout so the `Toolbar` is outside of the `DrawerLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

insert this in your nav view

```
app:insetForeground="@android:color/transparent"
```